# how can we import big sql file size 5gb into mysql database

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

i have sql file size 4.93 gb which i am not able to import into my database using mysql command.

--file was exported by using mysqldump command--

i've tried set connect_timeout=10 , max_allowed_packet=1G,
tried to import sql file into DB using sequel ace

command being used : mysql -u username -h hostname -p dbname < file.sql

error : ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 8207: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: @eric-william-nord  any idea. Please share your views

Comment: @harti any idea. Please share your views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just increased connect_timeout and i was able to import big file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).